# Reading from a file descriptor in a non-blocking way with Perl

Tags: perl, fork, pipe

Let's say I have this:

```
pipe(READ,WRITE);
$pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    close(READ);
    # do something that may be blocking
    print WRITE "done";
    close(WRITE);
    exit(0);
} else {
    close(WRITE);
    $resp = <READ>;
    close(READ);
    # do other stuff
}
```

In this situation, it's possible for the child to hang indefinitely. Is there a way I can read from `READ` for a certain amount of time (ie, a timeout) and if I don't get anything, I proceed in the parent with the assumption that the child is hanging?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in C or Perl, you use **select()** to test if there is any input available.  You can specify a timeout of **0** if you like, though used **1 second** in the example below.:

```
use IO::Select;
pipe(READ,WRITE);
$s = IO::Select->new();
$s->add(\*READ);
$pid = fork();
if ($pid == 0) {
    close(READ);
    # do something that may be blocking
    for $i (0..2) {
        print "child - $i\n";
        sleep 1;
    }
    print WRITE "donechild";
    close(WRITE);
    print "child - end\n";
    exit(0);
} else {
    print "parent - $pid\n";
    close(WRITE);
    for $i (0..10) {
        print "parent - $i\n";
            # 1 second wait (timeout) here.  Can be 0.
        print "parent - ", (@r=$s->can_read(1))?"yes":"no", "\n";
        last if @r;
    }

    $resp = <READ>;
    print "parent - read: $resp\n";
    close(READ);
    # do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can read from READ for a certain amount of time (ie, a timeout) and if I don't get anything, I proceed in the parent with the assumption that the child is hanging?

When you fork, you are working with two entirely separate processes. You're running two separate copies of your program. Your code cannot *switch* back and forth between the parent and child in your program. You're program is either the parent or the child.

You can use [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) in the parent to send a *SIGALRM* to your parent process. If I remember correctly, you set your `$SIG{ALRM}` subroutine, start your alarm, do your read, and then set `alarm` back to zero to shut it off. The whole thing needs to be wrapped in an `eval`.

I did this once a long time ago. For some reason, I remember that the standard system read didn't work. You have to use [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html). See [Perl Signal Processing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) for more help.

Comment: Right, I get that. I'm just trying to make a non-blocking read on a file descriptor from a pipe that the two processes are sharing. I should be able to do that somehow no? I'm trying to say "read from this end of the pipe RIGHT NOW and keep going - don't wait for something to show up"